# How can I have subscription to download limited products in limited time in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscription

I want to sell downloadable products with Woocommerce. Now I want to create some subscription package. so my customers can buy products or buy subscription and download for example 10 products in 1 month.
Is there any plugin to have this in Woocommerce or any other plugin like Woocommerce or any other cms like Joomla or any other Ecommerce software like Prestashop?
Pay attention please my first option is Woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

As per our analysis for your requirements there is currently no plugin which is provides this kind of functionality up til now. You can very well use a custom code to create this kind of functionality on your site for WooCommerce.

Approach here would be as follows:

- Restrict all WooCommerce products and WooCommerce Subscription products from buying for all users. Restrict all the users on bases of whether the user has a Subscription package active or not.
- Create your subscription Package product which we will be available for all users to buy. Set the attributes of the products like the Purchase limit.
- Once a subscription package is purchased by a user set a meta field for that user with the limits specified in Subscription Package Attributes.
- If a subscription package is active for a user check for whether the user has exhausted the purchase limit. if not then show the add to cart button if the customer has exhausted the purchase limit restrict the user from buying.

This way you can restrict the Customer to limit there purchase (custom field) for limit time (using WooCommerce Subscription daily/weekly/monthly/yearly) with custom coding in a custom plugin.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time and your answer, but I want all users may buy both products and subscription optionally. so if someone wanted to buy 1 product, he would be able to do it.and if someone wanted to buy one month subscription and download 10 product in month, he would be able to do it too.